# I need help with PWM filter capacitor current calculation

Tags: power, power-electronics, pwm, three-phase

PWM filter capacitor current calculation.

I am trying to select the capacitor for the PWM filter shown below. That being the case,  I need to calculate the total current (fundamental + harmonics) flowing through the capacitor C1. The RMS phase to phase voltage amplitude of the harmonics and fundamental are shown in the table.
L1 = L2 = L3 = 200 uH C1 = C2 = C3 = 300 uF switching frequency = 2Khz

@ 60.1 Hz from the table below, we can see that the phase-to-phase voltage is 439.3 volts. Therefore, the phase to neutral voltage is 439.3/1.73 = 254 volts. So, the current flowing through C1 is 28 amps.  jWL = .074 ohms and 1/jWC = 11.46 ohms. Are my calculations correct?

Similarly, @1880 Hz the current through C1 is 22 amps.
So, if you sum up all the currents, one will get 121 amps flowing through C1. Is this correct?

[image: BlockDiagram]

[image: Table]

Comment: missing assumptions, DCR, ESR. Ron, pk or rms ...  half/full bridge or tri-level?

Comment: DCR of L is 2.5 mOhm, voltage is RMS and its 2 level inverter. I haven't selected the cap, so I don't have ESR data. By Ron do you mean on resistance of IGBT?

Comment: Why do you need the current through the caps when, as drawn, it looks like a 3-phase LC lowpass (for the PWM)? Are you sure you don't need the harmonics of the output *voltage*?

Comment: You are correct, its a 3-phase LC lowpass for the PWM. The cap manufacturer asked for the current through the cap. I am surprised at the value I am calculating. I am good if the harmonics ( voltage THD) at the output is less than 10%

Comment: What is the output current rating for the motor/drive under the conditions you are calculating the filter?

Comment: The full load rating is 300 amps at 480 volts.